# can't update value in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Hi all i need help with my IndexedDB code i have 3 different input fields for 3 objects which i should update (add value to old value) i try to use that code but is not working. I start learnig IDB today but i stack for few hours now with that problem.

it's not update the value, when i add alert(newValue) after request.onsuccess i see proper value in alert box but objectStore.put(request.result) dont update DB. i look in the resources in developer tools

[alertBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX9Vk.jpg)
[After alert box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuDlJ.jpg)

My DB looks like:

```
{id: id1, value1: number, value2: number, value3: number},
{id: id2, value1: number, value2: number, value3: number},
{id: id3, value1: numer, value2: numer, value3: number}]
```

each value have own input box

```
$("#ospAdd").on("keydown",function search(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 13) {
                    var value1 = $("#ospAdd").val();
                    var id = "osp"


                    var transaction = db.transaction(["data"], "readwrite");
                    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("data");


                    request = objectStore.get(id);

                    request.onsuccess = function(event){
                        var value1 = $("#ospAdd").val();
                        var oldValue = Number(request.result.value1);
                        var newValue = oldValue + value1;
                        alert(newValue);
                        request.result.value1 = newValue;

                        objectStore.put(request.result);

                    };
                };

            });
```

Comment: What doe "not working" mean? What errors did you get? Did you look at the DB in the developer tools? Did anything get written?

Comment: its not update the value when i add  alert(newValue) after request onsuccess i see proper value in alert box but objectStore.put(request.result) dont update DB i look in the resources in developer tools

Comment: Please edit your question to include this important information so that others can see it.

Comment: Does the call to `objectStore.put()` throw? (That would be the case if you have out-of-line keys) If not, change the code to `var r2 = objectStore.put( ... );` and add `r2.onsuccess = function() { alert('ok'); };` and `r2.onerror = function() { alert(r2.error.name, r2.error.message); };` to confirm that it is succeeding or, if failing, what the error is is.

Comment: When i add parameter to put(..) i get this errorUncaught DataError: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The object store uses in-line keys and the key parameter was provided. . But i chage the code to use r2 onerror and success but it seams that put method is never used i dont get any allert from success or error

Comment: i found the problem. If i use same function in button and use onClick its working perfectly (without page reload). But when i use onkeydown function after hit enter its reload page and dont put new value.

Comment: Heh, yeah, a reload would do that. :) Use `e.preventDefault();` to stop the enter keypress from triggering the form submit.